# How do I shave a few KB off a PDF?

Tags: pdf

I have a scanned greyscale PDF of a set of official school transcripts that has been compressed to 1MB. Actually, its 1023655 bytes. I am trying to upload the document to an online application that has a maximum file size of 1MB.

My attempts to further compressing the PDF via the same website have not worked.
I have tried using Neevia, but any further compression makes the lightest of the three pages completely white (the first two pages are black printed on a blue background, and third is light grey printed on a white background)

I've tried using mac preview to save as black and white (unreadable), and to resize it (blurry).

I have GIMP at my disposal, but otherwise I don't have any experience with photo or document manipulation. How do I shave those kilobytes off this PDF?

Comment: if it is an image save it as a jpeg and lower the resolution.  You can also download PDF Creator from sourceforge and you will get the ability to set DPI and such.

Comment: It is a pdf, I'm not sure if that's the same as an image. When I try to convert from pdf to jpg via command line, it becomes unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at the bit depth of the grey scale.  For example, if it's currently 16-bit grey scale (2^16, or 65536 shades of grey), you could try using an 8-bit grey scale (256 shades) or 4-bit (16 shades).  You've already tried one form of this, going to 1-bit (2 shades, i. e. black and white), but without first taking a look at adjusting the contrast to make the text *really* stand out, you'll often end up with illegible files.

Comment: How do I look at the bit depth of grey scale?

Comment: The Imagemagick tool `identify` will show you all the characteristics of a file, e. g. `FileName.pdf[0] PDF 595x842 595x842+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 126KB 0.000u 0:00.019`

Answer (score 0):

If you download and install CutePDF, you can open the PDF file and go to print it, select the CutePDF printer, and you will be prompted to save a new PDF file. Chances are this new PDF file will be much smaller,

Comment: It looks like CutePDF is for windows only.